# What's the intended usage scenario of the Cat5e runs in my new house?

Tags: ethernet

We are buying a new house, and I was curious about this junction box. It has several lines of coax and cat5e in it.

Each room has a blank plate, and behind it is a coax and a cat5e drop.

I was assuming that when we get Comcast,I could put the modem in this closet, with a router and switch, put ends on each Ethernet cable, and have wired connection in most rooms.

But then I looked closer and realized that 6 of the Ethernet cables are wired to 2 other Ethernet cords, using only 2 wires from each cable.
Any ideas as to what this setup is?

[image]

Comment: Your builder can't tell you? Seems like the kind of knowledge you're paying for.

Comment: But they're probably phone lines.

Comment: @isherwood that'd be ideal yea, but he's not been very helpful. House was built in November, and we're just buying it from a bank now. And there are no phone jacks in the house anywhere, so I don't think they are for phones.

Comment: Network jacks are often hybrid phone jacks, and phone lines can use network plugs. You wouldn't necessarily see conventional phone jacks.

Comment: Shame they're not labeled properly. I'd be mapping it out. Check continuity between two colors at one end while someone shorts the same two wire colors in each room. Shouldn't take long.

Comment: @isherwood definitely will take the time to label them properly.

Comment: That's 99.9% certain wired for use as a shared phone line to all the rooms. The blue pair is usually unused in <=100Mbps Ethernet, so it's often used as a phone line in the shared cable. But it you want 1Gbps Ethernet then you'll need all 4 pairs.

Comment: @brhans if it's shared phone line, then I should be able to terminate that. Tuck those 2 (presumably going to the street) off to the side, and use the other 6 lines for Ethernet

Comment: @DickieScoob, yeah, you have basically two options: 1) leave the blue pairs as-is for phones, and use the other pairs for 100Mbps ethernet, or 2) ditch the phone lines, and use all four pairs of each cable for gigabit ethernet.  Personally, I haven't used a landline in over a decade, so I'd go with option 2, but ymmv.

Comment: @NateS. I haven't used a landline since...2004? Lol. Def not needed in our situation

Comment: What type of jacks _do_ you have in the house -- what do these cables run to? A look at the design of the jack and the wiring on the back side, if possible, would help determine whether they can be converted to Ethernet use.

Comment: @KevinReid in most rooms, there are blank plates. When I pull the plate off, in the box is a single Ethernet and coax cable. This is aside from the obvious electrical outlets on every wall.  So that is why I believe I'll be able to make it work as Ethernet

Answer (score 4):

Summarizing what has been said in the comments:

Having the blue pair paralleled between all the cables strongly suggests the builders intent was that they be used for phones. Cat5e cable is often used for phone wiring as it's more interference resistant than regular phone wire and the blue pair is the conventional "first pair" for phone wiring.

As for your options, there are two main ways forward.

Option 1, ditch the phone wiring cut off the builders mess and terminate the cables individually as network cables with all four pairs. This will let you run gigabit networking.

Option 2, leave the phone wiring as it is and use the green and orange pairs of each cable for Ethernet, this will limit you to 100 megabits per second.